# Replace string with dictionary value

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, data-structures

I have following text file

```
term term_1 
{ 
protocol:: tcp 
destination-port:: 23,24
action:: discard  
 }

term_2 
{ 
source-address:: x.x.x.x
protocol:: udp
action:: accept  
 }


term term_3 
{ 
protocol:: tcp 
destination-port:: 21,22,80,443  
 action:: accept  
  }

term_4
{ 
accept_rest
 }
```

Target is to replace port value with correct service name
I was able to get the txt file in a dictionary of dictionary and now i have available the following

```
policy_dict["term_1"]["protocol"] -> TELNET SSH_TEST

policy_dict["term_2"]["protocol"] -> FTP_TCP SSH HTTP HTTPS
```

How can be an easy way now to exchange port number with service name?
Reading the txt file line by line matching  term and destination port and than try to exchange value between file and dictionary seems complicate and not easy to read.
At the end i would like  to have as txt file the following:

```
term term_1 
{ 
protocol:: tcp 
destination-port:: TELNET SSH_TEST
action:: discard  
 }

term_2 
{ 
source-address:: x.x.x.x
protocol:: udp
action:: accept  
 }


term term_3 
{ 
protocol:: tcp 
destination-port:: FTP_TCP SSH HTTP HTTPS 
 action:: accept  
  }

term_4
{ 
accept_rest
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Reading the txt file line by line matching term and destination port and than try to exchange value between file and dictionary seems complicate and not easy to read."* I think that's exactly what you should do. Can you explain what it is that you find complicated about it? Python has useful tools to process lines of text, such as `str.startswith('destination-port')` and `str.split('::')` and `str.strip()`.

Comment: Note one important trick: read from one file, and write to another file. Don't try to write in the file that you're currently reading, unless you're already proficient with file manipulation and know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Proposed algorithm: Read the text file line by line. For every line: if it doesn't start with `'destination-port'`, then write the line directly to your output file. If it does start with `'destination-port'`, then find the relevant value in your dictionary, and write `'destination-port:: {}'.format(value)` to your output file. You need to keep track of which "term" you're in. If all terms are called "term", you can update a variable when the line starts with "term". If terms can have any name, then you can use the `{` as indicators of where terms start.

Comment: The only missing part in your proposal is replace correct destination port based on value of term and protocol. It is  unfortunately not only question to match for destination-port. With regard to update txt file yeah the correct way to go should by using fileinput.FileInput.